# How to chain api calls in a way to use a second api call to download images from first api call?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, async-await

I am using an api to parse data from an xml file. I am able to parse most of the data with one api call. Each object has Title, source, comment, action, objectkey and other properties that I can easily parse. However I also need an image property. The image is not listed in the xml file but an object key is which I can then use in a second api call to parse the image. How do I do this in a way so that I can bind to the same listbox so that each object has all their properties including the image from the second api call?

Someone mentioned that Async might be the way to go but I am not sure....

```
XDocument streamFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));
                var data = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("interaction")
                           select new Interaction
                           {
                                 title  = (string)query.Element("title"),
                                 displayName = (string)query.Element("displayName"),
                                 action = (string)query.Element("action"),                               
                                 userId   = (string)query.Element("userId"),
                                 objectKey = ((string)query.Element("objectKey")),
                                 timestamp = (string)query.Element("timestamp"),
                                 comment = (string)query.Element("comment"),
                                 source = (string)query.Element("source"),
                                 image =  getImage() ---> I imagine the second api call here


                           };


                streamListBox.ItemsSource = data;



            }
            catch (Exception e)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        });
    }

    public string getImage(string key)
    {
                    api calls here =>
        {


            try
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(response.Content);
                XDocument streamFeed = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(response.Content));
                var data2 = from query in streamFeed.Descendants("movie")
                           select new Object
                           {
                               image = (string)query.Element("image"),
                           };



                //streamListBox.ItemsSource = data2;


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }



            // MessageBox.Show(image);

        });
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Is the response.Content in getImage() different than then response at the first function and is it different per item?

Comment: So whats the problem with this code now? try to return data2.First() and see